# Is there a way to use BeautifulSoup with self extending pages like Facebook?

Tags: python, ajax, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Some web pages extend themselves, via ajax presumably, when you get near the bottom, Facebook being a well known example. I am particularly interested in screenscraping Filmstruck's movie listing page. It does have an end but you can see it adding movies as you scroll down. Is there a way to use BeautifulSoup to get all the content on the page?

https://www.filmstruck.com/us/watch/browse-all/

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Many large dynamic sites have a public, documented API that you can use without having to scrape the HTML and/or have terms of service that don’t allow you to use their site programmatically and will actively detect attempts to do so and break them. So, the first thing you should do is read their site to see if either or both of those is true.

Comment: If scraping is both required and allowed, then `BeautifulSoup` (with `requests` or similar) won’t do it on its own. You need to either run a JS interpreter or reverse engineer the requests made by their JS code and implement them yourself—or just drive a browser or browser engine using something like Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

No `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` or `urllib` can be used generally in static webpages unlike facebook where the page loads new data everytime. If you're going to scrape dynamic sites like Facebook it's better to use a tool like `selenium` to load the page and then use `BeautifulSoup` or directly access with `selenium`